# How to return a useEffect with only if statements in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using a **useEffect** to define a variable value when I enter in the page, but sometimes I get the following warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

Here is my code of the useEffect function:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(hierarchy == '1'){
            setJob('Investigador')
        }
        if(hierarchy == '2'){
            setJob('Administrador')
        }
        if(hierarchy == '0'){
            setJob('Novo Utilizador')
        }
}, [])
```

I know that i should return something in the function to clean it up, but since i'm using only if's and not a const, how can I return in order not have this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **cleanup function** when you set states in your app.
Consider using `'mounted'` variable, to tell whether it should skip the call to setState or not.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
    
    //inside component:
    const mounted = useRef(true);
    useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true;
     if (mounted.current) {
            if(hierarchy == '1'){
                setJob('Investigador')
            }
            if(hierarchy == '2'){
                setJob('Administrador')
            }
            if(hierarchy == '0'){
                setJob('Novo Utilizador')
            }
    }
     return () => (mounted.current = false);
    }, [])
```

Comment: Can i use it like this for every similar useEffect function?

Comment: Yes, you can use this!

Comment: Please check out the updated answer. I forgot to add `if (mounted.current) {}`